# How to call .env file from YAML?

Tags: yaml, serverless-framework, pyyaml

I want to hide my secret credential from my yaml, i need to use .env, so how to call .env file from my yaml, so that every I call this YAML, YAML will automatic call .env file. Please help me. thx

Comment: This is kinda awkward , why you want to maintain 2 files like this?
use `.env` or `YAML` .
as of i know. there you cant call ` .env ` from yaml

Comment: YAML is a markup language. A YAML document is not a program, it does not **do** anything. Now, perhaps the program you feed your document into does some special handling for what you want, but you should refer to your program's documentation for that (or at least describe your full context here).

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using an `.env` file, which is a simple properties file if you're following [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package, you can do the following:

1. create additional `.yml` file, for example `.secrets.yml`. you can store the secrets per stage:

```yaml
prod:
  MY_SECRET: foo
dev:
  MY_SECRET: bar
```

2. store your secrets/configurations there

Then in `serverless.yml`:

3. load this file into an object:

```yaml
custom:
  secrets: ${file(.secrets.yml):${self:provider.stage}}
```

4. load object fields as environment variables:

```yaml
provider:
  environment:
    MY_SECRET: ${self:custom.secrets.MY_SECRET}
```

**How to test locally**

In your tests you can load the secrets file this way:

```javascript
const yaml = require('js-yaml');
const fs = require('fs');
const _ = require('lodash');

module.exports.loadSecrets = function (env = 'dev', path = './.secrets.yml') {
    const secrets = yaml.load(fs.readFileSync(path));
    _.forEach(secrets[env], (value, key) => {
        process.env[key] = value;
    });
}
```

Reference: http://www.goingserverless.com/blog/using-environment-variables-with-the-serverless-framework